# ClosedXML - Add a new row without overwrite data (first line)

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm trying to add an empty row before filling my excel document.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    sda.Fill(dt);

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Report");
        var listOfStrings = new List<String>();
        ws.Cell(1, 6).Value = "Service";
        ws.Cell(1, 15).Value = "Invoice";

        ws.Range("A1:L1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkBlue;
        ws.Range("M1:Q1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkCandyAppleRed;
        ws.Range("M2:Q2").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xlsx");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

I only need to make the first row empty and then fill the document with my data.
But all time I'm overwriting the document.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To insert one row above the first row in the worksheet use this:

```
ws.Row(1).InsertRowsAbove(1);
                       // ^ number of rows to insert
```

There is also the method `InsertRowsBelow()` to insert new rows below a certain row. See the [documentation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-and-Deleting-Rows) for more examples.